# Entity Framework calling Oracle package which is calling SQL Server database through dblink

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

We are calling an Oracle package which is calling SQL Server database table through dblink from Entity Framework 4.0 and EF is throwing error

> ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
>   ORA-02063: preceding line from RETCLD

Can anyone please help me? Any help will be really appreciated

Thanks

Comment: EF or Oracle throwing the error? It looks like Oracle is throwing them. Does the package have an Oracle cursor?

Comment: yes package have oracle cursor in it.